# Fetch SVN repo data using trac python library

Tags: python, svn, trac

I want to migrate tickets from Trac to GitLab.
In order to replicate the setup, I have hosted a trac server on Ubuntu VM with SVN as repository type and default db.
I need to write a script which will fetch changeset data i.e. commit data.
This changeset data also needs to be migrated.
Trac provides packages such as trac.core.*, trac.versioncontrol.api.*, etc to fetch repository details
I have added the repository data to my trac.ini file as well which looks like below:

```
[repositories]

.dir = /home/sneha/svn-trac

.type = svn
```

I have written a small script just to check if it even connects to the svn repo configured in trac.ini.

```
from trac.core import ComponentManager
from trac.versioncontrol.api import RepositoryManager
cm = ComponentManager()
rm = RepositoryManager(cm)
print rm.get_repositories_by_dir('/home/sneha/svn-trac')
```

Error after executing the script:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "changeset.py", line 5, in
>   
>       print rm.get_repositories_by_dir('/home/sneha/svn-trac')   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/versioncontrol/api.py", line 535,
>   in get_repositories_by_dir   File
>   "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/versioncontrol/api.py", line 647,
>   in get_all_repositories   File
>   "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/versioncontrol/api.py", line 132,
>   in get_repositories
>   **AttributeError: 'DbRepositoryProvider' object has no attribute 'env'**

Is it compulsory to configure DB repository too for trac to fetch me repo details?
Pease help.

Comment: Where in GitLab do you intend to migrate the changeset data? Trac just pulls data from the SVN repository, so you can grab the data yourself from SVN. Or, you can dump the database tables directly from the Trac database. That said, the immediate problem with your script is that you shouldn't create a `ComponentManager` instance. Create an `Environment` instance instead, and pass that to `RepositoryManager`. Instantiate the `Environment` object like this: `env = Environment('/path/to/trac/environment')`.

Comment: There are commits which correspond to a ticket and we have CommitTicketUpdater plugin enabled. So if one commits a change to SVN and adds a comment as "refs #<ticketid>", then a message is added to the ticket mentioned in the comment. We want to migrate the changelog as it appears in trac to gitlab. So for that what I have to do is, first fetch all changeset id's mentioned in the comments of the tickets and create similar commits in gitlab and then mention the new commit id in the changelog of gitlab ticket so that the reference is not lost even when we have new ticket numbers or commit ids.

Comment: Sample changelog comment added due to the CommitTicketUdpated plugin:                                                                                                                        -refs #1757
(See Changelog [13462])                                                                                    Here 1757 is the ticket id and 13462 is the commit id.